# Is it wrong to ask a question right after a similar question was asked by me a few minutes ago?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, duplicate-questions

For example,

I asked a question about the execution performance of a *SQL* query using `LIMIT` and without using it.

Minutes after, I thought about a very similar question, but not related to `LIMIT`, but related to restrictions in the `WHERE` clause.

**What should I do?**

- Edit my question and ask the other question there too? (I don't think that would be proper)
- Ask the other question, although it is very similar to the first one?

Comment: Not wrong, IMHO, but there is some chances that would closed as exact duplicate.

Comment: You can do that but my opinion you shouldn't. That's not welcome. You should just **EDIT** your first post. With bold **EDIT**. So everyone can see it.

Comment: @Soner I know that, but I still don't see that is a good option, because then my question could be partially answered. I mean, a person could answer my first question and another one my second one. What answer should I accept?

Comment: No problem privided you link the questions to cheep other, lots of small questions can often get better answers then one large question.

Comment: I'd also vote yes, assuming it doesn't look likely the two similar questions will end up having exactly the same answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is *similar*, but not the same, then I would say it's fine. The questions are meant to be for particular things, not a general area. For example, if were to ask a question about apples (not to be done on this particular site), I would have to have a question about a particular thing (such as it's size). I would not get the "Full 5,000,000 word paper that describes every aspect". So, if the question is different, but still kinda related, go ahead and ask. Just don't go looking for the absolute or full definition of something.

Another fine example is a mouse event in programming (Im not going to focus on a language or anything). If you ask a question about, for instance, mouse dragging events, and then another about left-clicking, it's fine. If you just ask for mouse events in general, then ask about mouse events for blu-tooth, chances are that you are going to get flagged.

So, although I don't know the details, I think asking both of your questions within five minutes of each other is perfectly acceptable.